# Java issues on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have tried some scripting using jmeter, but I am getting issues.

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-02-10 13:57:36 IST
Load time: 1229
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1880
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1880
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to http://wwwe.google.com refused

Response headers:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Please help me o this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong url, change it by http://www.google.com